# How can I convert ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(1);
list.add("Java");
list.add(3.14);
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

I tried:

```
ArrayList<String> list2 = (String)list;
```

But it gave me a compile error.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I mean its not safe. Have a look at the example.

Comment: You're putting non-strings into the list. What is your expectation of what happens if you force them to be strings?

Comment: I assume you meant: ArrayList<String> list2 = (ArrayList<String>)list;

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Since this is *actually* not a list of strings, the easiest way is to loop over it and convert each item into a new list of strings yourself:

```java
List<String> strings = list.stream()
   .map(object -> Objects.toString(object, null))
   .toList();
```

Or when you're not on Java 16 yet:

```java
List<String> strings = list.stream()
   .map(object -> Objects.toString(object, null))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or when you're not on Java 8 yet:

```java
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
for (Object object : list) {
    strings.add(Objects.toString(object, null));
}
```

Or when you're not on Java 7 yet:

```java
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(list.size());
for (Object object : list) {
    strings.add(object != null ? object.toString() : null);
}
```

Note that you should be declaring against the interface ([`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) in this case), not the implementation.

Comment: I like how null values are preserved this this implementation.

Comment: If you use `String.valueOf(object)`, you won't have to do the `object != null ? object.toString() : null` thing

Comment: @Tomas: it would add a string with value `"null"` instead of the literal `null`. It depends further on the business requitements whether that's desireable or not. For me, it wouldn't have been acceptable at all as it introduces a potentially major bug.

Comment: @BalusC Oh, right... I'm curious, what would be the major bug? If you wanted a List of Strings, wouldn't it be better to have `"null"` instead of `null`?

Comment: @Tomas: `"null"` is not `null` at all. The `null` has a special meaning in Java. It makes no sense to be forced to do `if (item.equals("null"))` when checking for that afterwards.

Comment: @BalusC I know the difference :) But if I had `"null"`, I wouldn't  have to further check the list for `null`.

Comment: @Tomas: you're only defeating the strong typing nature of Java this way. But as said, it depends on the business requirements whether that's desireable. For me, that's simply unacceptable. Do whatever you want and the time will teach :)

Answer (score 16):

It's not safe to do that!
Imagine if you had:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(new Employee("Jonh"));
list.add(new Car("BMW","M3"));
list.add(new Chocolate("Twix"));
```

It wouldn't make sense to convert the list of those Objects to any type.

Comment: Unless they have [`Object#toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method overridden. However, the whole type conversion from X to String for other purposes than human presentation does indeed not make much sense.

Answer (score 16):

You can use wildcard to do this as following

```
ArrayList<String> strList = (ArrayList<String>)(ArrayList<?>)(list);
```

Answer (score 15):

Using Java 8 you can do:

```
List<Object> list = ...;
List<String> strList = list.stream()
                           .map( Object::toString )
                           .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to do it the dirty way, try this.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<String> convert(ArrayList<Object> a) {
   return (ArrayList) a;
}
```

Advantage: here you save time by not iterating over all objects.

Disadvantage: may produce a hole in your foot.

Answer (score 12):

Using [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<String> stringList=Lists.transform(list,new Function<Object,String>(){
    @Override
    public String apply(Object arg0) {
        if(arg0!=null)
            return arg0.toString();
        else
            return "null";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is another alternative using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

```
List<Object> lst ...    
List<String> ls = Lists.transform(lst, Functions.toStringFunction());
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code `ArrayList<String> list2 = (String)list;` does not compile because `list2` is not of type `String`. But that is not the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 lambda:

```
ArrayList<Object> obj = new ArrayList<>();
obj.add(1);
obj.add("Java");
obj.add(3.14);

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
obj.forEach((xx) -> list.add(String.valueOf(xx)));
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java Generics Takes a list of X and returns a list of T that extends or implements X, Sweet!

```
    // the cast is is actually checked via the method API
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends X, X> ArrayList<T> convertToClazz(ArrayList<X> from, Class<X> inClazz, Class<T> outClazz) {
    ArrayList<T> to = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (X data : from) {
        to.add((T) data);
    }
    return to;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
List<Object> lst  =listOfTypeObject;   
ArrayList<String> aryLst = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
        aryLst.add(lst.get(i).toString());
    }
```

Note: this works when the list contains all the elements of datatype String.