# Convert String ArrayList into ArrayList of own defined objects

Tags: java, list, collections, casting

Can someone guide me how to convert `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Object>` ??

Object is a class written by me with some getters and setters..

Comment: you can refer this discussion also... [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581407/how-can-i-convert-arraylistobject-to-arrayliststring)

Comment: **Never ever** name an own class `Object`, even though it is legal Java code.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object> lstObj = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(String str: strList){
  if(str==null)
     lstObj.add(null);
  }else{
     lstObj.add((Object)(str));
  }
}
```

Comment: I think he means a custom Object. not `java.lang.Object`

Comment: @The, `ArrayList<Object>` is mentioned explicitly in the OP.

Comment: @peter i didn't believe it either, however it does say in the question **Object is a class written by me..**

Comment: @The Scrum Meister - I think org.life.java noticed that (and quickly invented the custom constructor :-) )

Comment: @org.life.java - Jigar Joshi - no, no, revert your last change! The copy constructor was **the best** answer at all!!! As long as this `Object` is really a custom class or a "placeholder" name for any other class.

Comment: How to convert the same for `ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Object[]>`

Answer (score 0):

Have a constructor in your object that takes a string:

```
List<MyObject> myObjectList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
for ( String str : stringList )
{
  myObjectList.add( new MyObject( str ) );
}
```