# Cast an Arraylist of Doubles to ArrayList of Integers

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

I am trying to convert an ArrayList to ArrayList. I am having actually a list of labels in Double and I want to create a list of Integers. I am trying to add the one to another but of course I need a casting process.

```
ArrayList<Integer> lab = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lab.addAll(labels.data); //labels.data is an Arraylist of Doubles.
```

How can I cast one list to another??
I ve tried this to add one by one:

```
ArrayList<Integer> lab = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     for (int i = 0; i < labels.data.size(); i++) {

            lab.set(i, labels.data.get(i).intValue());

    }
```

But I received outOfBoundsError.

Comment: @snake_plissken Why do this?

Comment: Iterate on it and build a new `ArrayList`.

Comment: You can't, you have add them one by one. Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<String>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581407/how-can-i-convert-arraylistobject-to-arrayliststring)

Comment: You can add them one by one using a cast lab.add( labels.get(i).intValue() ) or something like this

Comment: You will have to do one by one conversion in loop and add it to list. This should help in conversion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102318/cast-double-to-integer-in-java

Comment: Because I ve got several spaghetti functions that works with ArrayList<Integers> and I think is better done it once in main function.

Comment: you hav to replace set(...) with add(...) since set throws a OutOfBounds Exception. You can use add with an index exactly like you do it with your set method. see also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not convert `List<Double>` to `List<Integer>` directly.  Loop on each `Double` object and call `intValue()` function to get the integer part of it. For e.g. 13.3 will give 13. I hope thats what you want.

```
for(Double d : labels.data){
    lab.add(d.intValue());
}
```

Comment: +1 for me thanks for the answer, but I can't explain the error in my edited code.

Comment: Please don't move the goalposts. This answers your original question. Adding new questions is not helpful.

Comment: @snakeplissken, You are receiving error because `set` function is used to replace the value in list, not add to it. Correct function to use is `add`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int, E)

Answer (score 8):

First, is there any need for this to be an ArrayList particularly, or for these to be the wrapper classes instead of the primitives? If not, working with a simple array will avoid the overhead of boxing and unboxing, and of storing a lot of objects.

That aside, you'd probably want to loop over the list and cast each item to a double (or a Double), then add it to a new array (or ArrayList). There isn't a bulk operation for this.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Arraylist<Number>`. A [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) is a parent of both `Double` and `Integer`, so you would be able to add Doubles to your list and the Number.intValue() will convert (autoboxing) into Integer when required.

```
  ArrayList<Number> list;

  list.add(new Double(17.7));
  Integer i = list.get(0).intValue(); // 18, rounding.
```

Comment: This is good. OP, I suggest that this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Changed to List Number.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting outOfBoundsError because you are using set() instead of add().  set() is a replacement command and requires there to already be an object in that position.