# Transform a List of List into into a List of another object

Tags: java

I use a method which returns a list of `List`s. This `List` contains 6 `List`s, each `List` contains 3 String : 
`[[5, 0.01, 2], [7, 0.01, 3], [3, 0.02, 2], [8, 0.05, 3],[9, 0.1, 2], [6, 0.1, 3]]`

Continuing from [a previous answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581407/how-can-i-convert-arraylistobject-to-arrayliststring.)

But I have to split again this list in 3 differents values :
 `[3, 0.01, 2]`

The main goal is to transform this list of object in list of Change.
A Change :

```
public class Change {
  private static final String value;
  private static final String amount;
  private static final String column;
...
}
```

I attempted but I think it's not the greatest way to accomplish :

```
List saisie = ServiceTableau.getInstance().deserialiser(quantites);
List<String> saisieToStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Object object : saisieIHM) {
    saisieIHMToStrings.add(object != null ? object.toString() : null);
}
```

Is there a system method to do this?
I can't use external libraries

Comment: Are you sure the fields in `Change` should be static?

Comment: Indeed while testing the solution I change it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a constructor in your `Change` class:

```
public Change( String input) {
    String[] values = input.split(",");
    this.value = values[0];
    this.amount = values[1];
    this.column = values[2];
}
```

And then pass that string when you create the list:

```
List<Change> saisieToStrings = new ArrayList<Change>();
for (Object object : saisieIHM) {
    saisieIHMToStrings.add( new Change( object.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Constructor should throw illegal argument EX if the `input` is not made correctly, proposed change.