# Converting List<Object> to String returns empty results

Tags: java, list

> **Disclaimer** : I'm using [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581407/how-can-i-convert-arraylistobject-to-arrayliststring/4581429#4581429), as reference for `List<Object>` to `List<String>` and [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array/17440755#17440755) for Java `List<String>` of strings to a JavaScript array.

I've `List<Seat>` and I want to get all values of it in a comma separated `String`, I tried in this way

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  

    public Rextester(){
        Seat seat1 = new Seat();
        seat1.setSeatNumber(1);

        Seat seat2 = new Seat();
        seat2.setSeatNumber(2);

        Seat seat3 = new Seat();
        seat3.setSeatNumber(3);


        List<Seat> seatList = new ArrayList<Seat>();
        seatList.add(seat1);
        seatList.add(seat2);
        seatList.add(seat3);
        Utility util = new Utility();
        String stringSeats = util.toJavascriptArray(seatList);
        System.out.println("JavaScriptArray is " + stringSeats);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Rextester();

    }



    private class Seat {

        private Integer seatNumber;        

        public Integer getSeatNumber() {
            return this.seatNumber;
        }

        public void setSeatNumber(Integer seatNumber) {
            this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
        }   
        public String toString() {
            return ""+ seatNumber;
        }
    }

    private class Utility {

        public String toJavascriptArray(List<Seat> listSeats){
            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Seat object : listSeats) {
                strings.add(object != null ? object.toString() : null);
            }
            String[] arr = new String[strings.size()];
            arr = strings.toArray(arr);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append("[");
            for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

                if(i+1 < arr.length){
                    sb.append(",");
                }
            }
            sb.append("]");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

but this gives me

```
JavaScriptArray is [,,]
```

on console, am I making some mistakes? an online working code is http://rextester.com/NDUGT61105

Comment: Everything is right.. besides the fact in the `toJavascriptArray(List<Seat> listSeats)` method... You aren't appending the string in there... just a comma

Comment: So add this in there... `sb.append(arr[i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't append iterated element, see below

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sb.append(arr[i]); // add this
            if (i + 1 < arr.length) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }
```

have a look at the `toString` implementations of `Arrays` and `List`

Simply you can return

```
strings.toString()
```

or

```
Arrays.toString(arr)
```

To get the expected result

Comment: Ok that is the point I was missing [added](http://rextester.com/DGZH57765) issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you're using Java 8 is using StringJoiner:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html

Comment: Thanks for your time and Sorry, but I'm using java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to append the array elements to the string buffer!
Add

```
sb.append(arr[i]);
```

inside the loop where you prepare the string buffer and everything is ok