# Convert a double array to a float array

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point, double

I have a double[][] array, and I want to get one row into a float[] array. Casting didn't worked at first, so I looked for something different.

I found [here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java) an elegant solution to convert Object[] to String[], which also would work if I were converting Object[] to float[].

So: is there any elegant way of converting double[] to float[], or a double[] to Object[] so I can use the code at the other post?

I'll provide an example code of what I'm doing, even I think it's not neccesary:

```
double[][] datos = serie.toArray();
double[][] testArray = {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}, {7.0, 8.0, 9.0}};
double[] doubleArray = Arrays.copyOf(testArray[1], testArray[1].length);
// This would be great but doesn't exist:
//float[] floatArray = Arrays.copyOf(doubleArray, doubleArray.length, float[].class);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, casting the array won't work. You need to explicitly convert each item:

```
float[] floatArray = new float[doubleArray.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < doubleArray.length; i++)
{
    floatArray[i] = (float) doubleArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a function you could place in a library and use over and over again:

```
float[] toFloatArray(double[] arr) {
  if (arr == null) return null;
  int n = arr.length;
  float[] ret = new float[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ret[i] = (float)arr[i];
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Use System.arrayCopy

Answer (score 4):

For future reference; this can also be done a bit more concisely by using Guava, like this:

```
double[] values = new double[]{1,2,3};

float[] floatValues = Floats.toArray(Doubles.asList(values));
```

Comment: looks really slow (possibly it's not, just saying it look slow). you tested this by any chance?

Comment: Nope, I didn't test the running time. It's probably not as fast as writing a loop, but if you're not doing this very often and/or for large lists it still shouldn't take a noticable amount of time.

Comment: ok, so i tested it. it's quite exactly 9 times slower on my machine. http://pastebin.com/Rh5eWY7q 
imho this shouldn't be used ever. it's just one line less, slower, more convoluted, and requires a huge dependency.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to test performance. I agree that it's overkill to include Guava just for this, but if you're using it already I do think this is clearer than the loop. Not so much because it saves two lines (not one), but because it saves the loop itself. This is subjective of course, but in my mind a loop is usually an indication of complexity, something that merits attention when reading code. That's why I prefer the snippet I posted. As I explained, I will usually not really care about the performance of such a function, and I don't agree this is more convoluted than a loop.

Answer (score 4):

With Kotlin you can try something like this:

```
 val doubleArray = arrayOf(2.0, 3.0, 5.0)
 val floatArray = doubleArray.map { it.toFloat() }.toFloatArray()
```

or

```
 val floatArray = arrayOf(2.0, 3.0, 5.0).map { it.toFloat() }.toFloatArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

I created this class for my own personal use but i think it can help you with your problem.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ArrayUtils {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ArrayUtils.class);
    private static final Map<Class, Class> primitiveMapping = new HashMap<Class, Class>();
    private static final Map<Class, Method> primitiveParseMethodLookup = new HashMap<Class, Method>();
    private static final Map<Class, Method> primitiveArrayGetMethodLookup = new HashMap<Class, Method>();
    private static final Map<Class, Method> valueOfMethodLookup = new HashMap<Class, Method>();

    static {

        // Initialize primitive mappings
        primitiveMapping.put(boolean.class, Boolean.class);
        primitiveMapping.put(byte.class, Byte.class);
        primitiveMapping.put(short.class, Short.class);
        primitiveMapping.put(int.class, Integer.class);
        primitiveMapping.put(float.class, Float.class);
        primitiveMapping.put(long.class, Long.class);
        primitiveMapping.put(double.class, Double.class);

        // Initialize parse, valueOf and get method lookup
        // We do that in advance because the lookup of the method takes the longest time
        // Compared to the normal method call it's 20x higher
        // So we use just the reflective method call which takes double the time of a normal method call
        try {
            primitiveParseMethodLookup.put(boolean.class, Boolean.class.getMethod("parseBoolean", new Class[]{String.class}));
            primitiveParseMethodLookup.put(byte.class, Byte.class.getMethod("parseByte", new Class[]{String.class}));
            primitiveParseMethodLookup.put(short.class, Short.class.getMethod("parseShort", new Class[]{String.class}));
            primitiveParseMethodLookup.put(int.class, Integer.class.getMethod("parseInt", String.class));
            primitiveParseMethodLookup.put(float.class, Float.class.getMethod("parseFloat", String.class));
            primitiveParseMethodLookup.put(long.class, Long.class.getMethod("parseLong", String.class));
            primitiveParseMethodLookup.put(double.class, Double.class.getMethod("parseDouble", String.class));

            valueOfMethodLookup.put(Boolean.class, Boolean.class.getMethod("valueOf", new Class[]{String.class}));
            valueOfMethodLookup.put(Byte.class, Byte.class.getMethod("valueOf", new Class[]{String.class}));
            valueOfMethodLookup.put(Short.class, Short.class.getMethod("valueOf", new Class[]{String.class}));
            valueOfMethodLookup.put(Integer.class, Integer.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));
            valueOfMethodLookup.put(Float.class, Float.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));
            valueOfMethodLookup.put(Long.class, Long.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));
            valueOfMethodLookup.put(Double.class, Double.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));

            primitiveArrayGetMethodLookup.put(boolean.class, Array.class.getMethod("getBoolean", new Class[]{Object.class, int.class}));
            primitiveArrayGetMethodLookup.put(byte.class, Array.class.getMethod("getByte", new Class[]{Object.class, int.class}));
            primitiveArrayGetMethodLookup.put(short.class, Array.class.getMethod("getShort", new Class[]{Object.class, int.class}));
            primitiveArrayGetMethodLookup.put(int.class, Array.class.getMethod("getInt", Object.class, int.class));
            primitiveArrayGetMethodLookup.put(float.class, Array.class.getMethod("getFloat", Object.class, int.class));
            primitiveArrayGetMethodLookup.put(long.class, Array.class.getMethod("getLong", Object.class, int.class));
            primitiveArrayGetMethodLookup.put(double.class, Array.class.getMethod("getDouble", Object.class, int.class));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

            //******************************
            // This can never happen
            //******************************
        }

    }

    public static boolean isArrayOfPrimitives(Object object) {

        if (object.getClass().isArray()) {
            return object.getClass().getComponentType().isPrimitive();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isArrayOf(Object object, Class clazz) {

        if (object.getClass().isArray()) {
            return clazz.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass().getComponentType());
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Convert any array of primitives(excluding char), strings or numbers into any other array
     * of strings or numbers.
     *
     * @param array                       Array of primitives(excluding char), strings or numbers
     * @param convertedArrayComponentType Converted array component type (String or Number)
     * @param <T>                         To allow implicit casting
     * @return Array of convertedArrayComponentType
     */
    public static <T> T[] convertArray(Object array, Class<T> convertedArrayComponentType) {

        // Collect data regarding arguments
        final boolean arrayOfPrimitives = isArrayOfPrimitives(array);
        final boolean arrayOfCharPrimitives = isArrayOf(array, char.class);
        final boolean arrayOfCharacters = isArrayOf(array, Character.class);
        final boolean arrayOfStrings = isArrayOf(array, String.class);
        final boolean arrayOfNumbers = isArrayOf(array, Number.class);

        // Check if array is an array of strings, primitives or wrapped primitives
        if (!arrayOfPrimitives && !arrayOfNumbers && !arrayOfStrings || arrayOfCharPrimitives || arrayOfCharacters) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(array + " must be an array of of strings, primitives or boxed primitives (byte, boolean, short, int, float, long, double)");
        }

        // Check if it's assignable from Number of String
        if (!Number.class.isAssignableFrom(convertedArrayComponentType) && !String.class.isAssignableFrom(convertedArrayComponentType)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(convertedArrayComponentType + " must be a Number or a String");
        }

        try {
            return (T[]) convertArrayInternal(array, convertedArrayComponentType);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

            // This can happen due to errors in conversion
            throw (RuntimeException) e.getTargetException();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // This should never happen
            log.error("Something went really wrong in ArrayUtils.convertArray method.", e);
        }

        // To satisfy the compiler
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Convert any array of primitives(excluding char), strings or numbers into an array
     * of primitives(excluding char).
     *
     * @param array                       Array of primitives(excluding char), strings or numbers
     * @param convertedArrayComponentType Converted array component type primitive(excluding char)
     * @return Array of convertedArrayComponentType
     */
    public static Object convertToPrimitiveArray(Object array, Class convertedArrayComponentType) {

        // Collect data regarding arguments
        final boolean arrayOfPrimitives = isArrayOfPrimitives(array);
        final boolean arrayOfCharPrimitives = isArrayOf(array, char.class);
        final boolean arrayOfCharacters = isArrayOf(array, Character.class);
        final boolean arrayOfStrings = isArrayOf(array, String.class);
        final boolean arrayOfNumbers = isArrayOf(array, Number.class);

        // Check if array is an array of strings, primitives or wrapped primitives
        if (!arrayOfPrimitives && !arrayOfNumbers && !arrayOfStrings || arrayOfCharPrimitives || arrayOfCharacters) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(array + " must be an array of of strings, primitives or boxed primitives (byte, boolean, short, int, float, long, double)");
        }

        // Check if it's assignable from Number of String
        if (!convertedArrayComponentType.isPrimitive() || convertedArrayComponentType.isAssignableFrom(char.class)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(convertedArrayComponentType + " must be a primitive(excluding char)");
        }

        try {
            return convertArrayInternal(array, convertedArrayComponentType);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

            // This can happen due to errors in conversion
            throw (RuntimeException) e.getTargetException();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // This should never happen
            log.error("Something went really wrong in ArrayUtils.convertArray method.", e);
        }

        // To satisfy the compiler
        return null;
    }

    private static Object convertArrayInternal(Object array, Class convertedArrayComponentType) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

        // Lookup the primitive parse method or the boxed primitive valueOf method
        final Method convertMethod;
        if (convertedArrayComponentType.isPrimitive()) {
            convertMethod = primitiveParseMethodLookup.get(convertedArrayComponentType);
        } else {
            convertMethod = valueOfMethodLookup.get(convertedArrayComponentType);
        }

        // If the array is an array of primitives lookup the get method
        final Method primitiveArrayGetMethod = primitiveArrayGetMethodLookup.get(array.getClass().getComponentType());

        // Get length and create new array
        final int arrayLength = Array.getLength(array);
        final Object castedArray = Array.newInstance(convertedArrayComponentType, arrayLength);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

            final Object value;
            if (primitiveArrayGetMethod != null) {
                value = primitiveArrayGetMethod.invoke(null, array, i);
            } else {
                value = Array.get(array, i);
            }

            final String stringValue = String.valueOf(value);
            final Object castedValue = convertMethod.invoke(null, stringValue);
            Array.set(castedArray, i, castedValue);
        }

        return castedArray;
    }

}
```

It can be used like this:

```
double[][] testArray = {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}, {7.0, 8.0, 9.0}};
double[] doubleArray = Arrays.copyOf(testArray[1], testArray[1].length);
float[] floatArray = (float[]) ArrayUtils.convertToPrimitiveArray(doubleArray, float.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Float
{
    var convertToDouble: [Double]
    {
        return compactMap { Double($0) }
    }
}

extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Double
{
    var convertToFloat: [Float]
    {
        return compactMap { Float($0) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin

```
val doubleArray = arrayOf(2.0, 3.0, 5.0)
val floatArray = FloatArray(doubleArray.size) { i -> doubleArray[i].toFloat() }
```