# Expand array without knowing its type

Tags: java, arrays

How can I expand an array without knowing its type?

I have an `Object[]`, and I know it contains only, say, `Car` instances. When I try to typecast it to a `Car[]`, it throws a ClassCastException. I'm working in an environment where Generics are not available.

Must I use a for-loop to copy each element manually into a new array like this:

```
Car[] cars = new Car[objects.length];
for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    cars[i] = (Car) objects[i];
}
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert object array to string array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java) - Yes, that's with `String[]`, but it's the same thing / reason / answer.

Comment: Hmm, don't think its a duplicate, as this is more about the runtime type of an arbitrary array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because the `Object[]` happens only to contain `Car`s, doesn't mean it can be cast to `Car[]`. You would need to copy the contents of the array to a new `Car[]`, casting where necessary.

Remember that arrays are themselves objects, and their type isn't governed by what's in them - it's the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 6, you can use [`copyOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28U%5b%5d,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29) to "resize" an array.

I don't now your actual problem, but a common solution to resize an array of arbitrary type in Java < 6 is:

```
Class elementType = oldArray.getClass().getComponentType();
Object[] newArray = (Object[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(elementType, newSize);
```

then you can use `System.arraycopy()` to copy values from the old array to the new one as needed.

Comment: I think the OP wants to change the type of the array, rather than just resize it - the question made it confusing by using the word "expand". Since the component type is known at compile time, reflection would be overkill anyway.

Comment: That may be true. And in that case, reflection is really not needed.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you can run into is if the array has primitives, then you cannot cast it to Object[].

You can make this work with both primitives and Objects by using some helpers on java.lang.reflect.Array.

This is an example of how to process an array safely and convert all the values to String.

```
public String[] stringifyValue(Object value) {
        String[] arrayValue;

 
        if (value.getClass().isArray() ){
            int arrayLength = Array.getLength(value);
            arrayValue = new String[arrayLength];

            for (int i=0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                arrayValue[i] = String.valueOf(Array.get(value, i));
            }
        }
    }
```