# Deserializing Arrays on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on a big app and I found a little Detail. It's possible to serialize Arrays and put them in a bundle. Then put it in a intent and start the activity. But on the receiving end I have to deserialize the array through a painful 2 step procedure.

```
     MyObj[] data = (MyObj[])bundle.getSerializable("key"); // doesn't work

     Object[] temp = (Object[])bundle.getSerializable("key");
     MyObj[] data2 = (MyObj[])temp, // doesn't work

     MyObj[] data3 = new MyObj[temp.length]; // does work
     for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
          data3[i] = (MyObj)temp[i];
     }
```

What's the reason that I have to go through looping through the array?

Comment: That is rather a general Java question than an Android specific one. Googling for "java casting arrays" will give answers to your problem. Java simply does not allow casting of Arrays downwards.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that if you have an array of `Object` that you cast to be an array of `MyObj`, the compiler would have to go through and verify the class of each of the items in the array to allow the cast to be `MyObj[]`.  The Java language designers made a decision to not do that and to force the programmer to write it out.  For example:

```
Object[] objs = new Object[] { "wow", 1L };
// this isn't allowed because the compiler would have to test each object itself
String[] strings = (String[]) objs;
// you wouldn't want an array access to throw the ClassCastException
String foo = strings[1];
```

So the Java language forces you to do the loop yourself.

```
Object[] objs = new Object[] { "wow", 1L };
String[] strings = new String[objs.length];
for (int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    // this can then throw a ClassCastException on this particular object
    strings[i] = (String) objs[i];
}
```

You can use the `Arrays` class (which uses the `System.arraycopy()` native method) to easily do this:

```
MyObj[] data3 = Arrays.copyOf(temp, temp.length, MyObj[].class);
```

See: [How to convert object array to string array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JSON with which it is very very easy to serialize and deserialize an array AND you don't have any ugly casts in your code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
String[] strings = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};

// Serialization
gson.toJson(ints);     ==> prints [1,2,3,4,5]
gson.toJson(strings);  ==> prints ["abc", "def", "ghi"]

// Deserialization
int[] ints2 = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4,5]", int[].class);
```

Example from: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples

Comment: I use Gson already for the json/rest communication to the server and it's slower than java de/serializing. So I think I use the casting.