# Integer[] not working in Intent#putExtra(...)

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, extra

I want to put an `int[]` into an Android Intent.  For various reasons I am getting a `LinkedList<Integer>`, so I tried (roughly) this:

```
LinkedList<Integer> myList = getIntegerList();
Intent intent = new Intent (context, class);
intent.putExtra("com.me.INTARRAY",  myList.toArray());
```

This didn't work because `toArray()` was giving me an `Object[]`.  I thought I could fix it by doing

```
intent.putExtra("com.me.INTARRAY", (Integer[]) myList.toArray(new Integer[myList.size()]) )
```

which does indeed produce an `Integer[]`; however, getting it out of the `Intent` STILL doesn't work.

Ultimately this isn't too hard to work around with a `for` loop so I ask more for curiosity than any other reason, but ... how do you get an `Integer[]` into an `Intent` extra as though it were an `int[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested this thoroughly, but I believe it should work. You can try it.

```
Integer[] integerArray = {/*something */ };
intent.putExtra("com.me.INTARRAY",  integerArray);
```

And then (not working)

<strike>Integer[] newArray = (Integer[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("com.me.INTARRAY");</strike>

**EDIT:**
Ahh.. After a little research and testing it seems the above is *not* possible. It is not possible because the compiler would have to iterate through every element to verify the cast. A solution(and I have testet it this time) would be to do this instead:

```
Object[] s = (Object[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("com.me.INTARRAY");
Integer[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(s, s.length, Integer[].class);
```

I found the explanation here: [Deserializing Arrays on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419028/deserializing-arrays-on-android)

Comment: Dang.  `for` loop it is then!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the array to int[] and pass it as extras using [putExtra(java.lang.String, int[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%5B%5D%29). On the other side you will need to get that extra using [getIntArrayExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntArrayExtra%28java.lang.String%29).

Here is the code that works fine, caller first and receiver follows:

```
LinkedList<Integer> myList = getIntegerList();;
int iArray[] = new int[myList.size()];
for (Integer i : myList)
iArray[myList.indexOf(i)] = i;
Intent intent = new Intent();// create your actual intent
intent.putExtra("com.your.package.name.int", iArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

and the other side:

```
int array[] = getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("com.your.package.name.int");
```

Another alternate, (which is better i guess) is to convert the LinkedList to Integer ArrayList. This works as follows, sender first receiver followed.

```
intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("com.your.package.name.array", new ArrayList<Integer>(myList));
```

and on the other side:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = getIntent().getExtras().getIntegerArrayList("com.your.package.name.array");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Not really I'm afraid, as this is exactly what I tried, and failed, to do.  In the end I used a `for` loop to insert the elements of the `LinkedList` into an array.

Comment: @Andrew Wyld: I'm afraid you would have used it wrong. Its for int[] and not Integer[]. I tried it at my end and works fine. Will also edit my post to add example code for you.

Comment: @AndrewWyld: The second alternative will rid you of the loop. And if this helps and works for you, remember to accept the answer :)

Comment: That's exactly what I did.  I wanted to know if you could get the array WITHOUT doing this.

Comment: What I failed to do was cast the array.  I was hoping it would be unnecessary to create a completely new array.