# Java: Copy array of Integers into Array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

Consider a method whose signature contains an `Integer` Array:

```java
public static void parse(Integer[] categories)
```

`parse` needs to call a different method, which expects an Array of Strings. So I need to convert `Integer[]` to `String[]`.

For example, `[31, 244] ⇒ ["31", "244"]`.

I've tried Arrays.copyOf described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java):

```java
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);
```

But got an `ArrayStoreException`.

I can iterate and convert each element, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: It's not a problem, but I thought there would be something more elegant, perhaps reminiscent of Python's list comprehension.

Comment: either way the bottom line is that java has to convert each element separately, so any way you can find may just look nicer, but executes a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not trying to avoid a loop then you can simply do:

```
String[] strarr = new String[categories.length];
for (int i=0; i<categories.length; i++)
     strarr[i] = categories[i] != null ? categories[i].toString() : null;
```

**EDIT:** I admit this is a *hack* but it works without iterating the original Integer array:

```
String[] strarr = Arrays.toString(categories).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Comment: -1 the question is:
"I can iterate and convert each element, but is there a more elegant way?"

Comment: I gave it a +1, not accepted it. And it might be the right answer if there isn't any one-liner.

Comment: so the right answer is something that you already knew isn't it?

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso: Pls check the **EDIT** section. Not sure about the elegance but it avoids the iteration of the original array.

Comment: I'm pretty much convinced that iterating is the Javaesque way. Thanks!

Comment: The second solution adds extraneous spaces to all string elements with an index greater than 0.

Comment: @simon: `.split("\\s*,\\s*");` will strip all spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually by iterating over the Int-Array and saving each element into the String-Array with a `.toString()` attached:

```
for(i = 0; i < intArray.length(); i++) {
    stringArray[i] = intArray[i].toString()
}
```

(Untested, but something like this should be the thing you are looking for)

Hmmm, just read your comment. I don't know any easier or more elegant way to do this, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think that theres a method for it:

use a loop for it like:

```
String strings[] = new String[integerarray.length];

for(int i = 0; i<integerarray.length;++i)
{
     strings[i] = Integer.toString(integerarray[i]);
}
```