# Casting Object to Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert object array to string array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java)

I am receiving an Object and casting it into a String array like this:

```
Object values[] = (Object[])request.getSession().getAttribute("userList");
String[] tmp = new String[values.length];
for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length; ++i) {
     tmp[i] = (String) values[i];
     out.println(tmp[i]);
}
```

Is there any better and cleaner way to do this?

Comment: when you call setAttribute() if you are passing a String[], you can just cast directly to that instead of using an object array as a proxy

Comment: @TritonMan - That should be an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not directly casting?

```
String values[] = (String[])request.getSession().getAttribute("userList");
```

Comment: Why not? Because `java.lang.ClassCastException` perhaps? Try `String[] arr = (String[])(new Object[]{"a", "b", "c"});`

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen if _getAttribute()_ is returning _Object[]_ why do you still cast it to _Object[]_ ?

Comment: Because [the return type of `HttpSession.getAttribute(...)` is `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) not `Object[]`.

Comment: Of note: `Object arr = (Object)(new Object[]{"a", "b", "c"});` does not throw an exception.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen but our concern is _Object[] x = (Object[]) obj;_, and your example is non-sense.