# Convert List<Object> to String[] in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I need to convert from `List<Object>` to `String[]`.

I made:

```
List<Object> lst ...
String arr = lst.toString();
```

But I got this string:

```
["...", "...", "..."]
```

is just one string, but I need String[]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you convert a random Object into a String?

Comment: toString is (in most classes) purely intended for diagnostic messages, not "production".

Comment: I want convert all list in String[] without iterate over it.

Comment: Did you look at the spec for List?  (I'm guessing not, otherwise you would have noticed toArray.)

Comment: Java 8 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002358/1216775

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to loop through the list and fill your `String[]`.

```
String[] array = new String[lst.size()];
int index = 0;
for (Object value : lst) {
  array[index] = (String) value;
  index++;
}
```

If the list would be of `String` values, List then this would be as simple as calling `lst.toArray(new String[0])`;

Comment: Change `array[index] = (String) value`, to `array[index] = String.valueOf( value )`.  The answer as it is will crash if the list contains anything, but Strings. Maybe this is what OP wants.

Answer (score 14):

You could use toArray() to convert into an array of Objects followed by [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1018798/1063716) to convert the array of Objects into an array of Strings:

```
Object[] objectArray = lst.toArray();
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);
```

Comment: Why additional array copy when `objectArray` can still be used as String[]?

Comment: See the bottom part of the linked question - casting `objectArray` to `String[]` causes a `ClassCastException`. This answer explains better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1018774/1063716

Comment: Yes in case of List containing objects other than string. But that happens even in your code.

Comment: `List<Object> lst = new ArrayList<Object>();
        lst.add(1);` I m getting ArrayStoreException for this test case.

Answer (score 11):

> Java 8

Java 8 has the option of using streams as well.

```
List<Object> lst = new ArrayList<>(); 
lst.add("Apple"); 
String[] strings = lst.stream().toArray(String[]::new); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));  // [Apple]
```

If we have a stream of `Object`, we would need an intermediate operation to do object-to-string conversion, and a terminal operation to collect the results. We can use `Objects.toString(obj, null)` or any other such implementation for string conversion.

```
String[] output = lst.stream()
    .map((obj) -> Objects.toString(obj, null))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: I had to do myObjects.stream().map(myObj::toString).toArray(String[]::new);

Answer (score 5):

If we are very sure that `List<Object>` will contain collection of `String`, then probably try this.

```
List<Object> lst = new ArrayList<Object>();
lst.add("sample");
lst.add("simple");
String[] arr = lst.toArray(new String[] {});
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

Lot of concepts here which will be useful:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Java","is","cool"}));
String[] a = new String[list.size()];
list.toArray(a);
```

**Tip to print array of Strings:**

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

```
List<Object> lst ...    
List<String> ls = Lists.transform(lst, Functions.toStringFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way available in Kotlin

```kotlin
var lst: List<Object> = ...
    
listOFStrings: ArrayList<String> = (lst!!.map { it.name })
```