# Converting from List<Object> to String[]

Tags: java

So far I found some answers here but I'll get everytime Errors that I cant convert from Object to String and so on for example I used now this idea:

I have that following List of Objects which is mapped with my Database:
`List<OPBList> list123`

now i tried this:

```
    String[] arr = list123.toArray(new String[] {});
    return arr;
```

heres m OPBList class:

```
     @Entity
     @Table(name = "T_OPB_LIST")
     @XmlRootElement
     @NamedQueries({
      @NamedQuery(name = "AllOPBLists", query = "Select a from OPBList a")
      })
     public class OPBList implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic
@XmlAttribute
@XmlID
private Long id;

@Basic
private String company;

@Basic
private String country;
```

with some getter and setter methodes

and I get this Error :

`HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ArrayStoreException`

Any Ideas how I can do that?

Comment: please, post OPBList class code.

Comment: @vishalgajera its just too long, plus too complicated but I try to explain it

Comment: You have things in the list that aren't Strings.

Comment: @immibis yes and I want to convert them to strings

Comment: [Convert List to String\[\] in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14773264)

Comment: @Tom thanks but I already read it and already tried all methodes there, it doesn`t work for me

Comment: Just use the accepted answer there and replace `array[index] = (String) value;` with `array[index] = value.toString();` or your string conversion method.

Comment: @Tom doing that I get this response com.package.test.persistence.OPBList;@40f98da8 and as I said using all other ideas gets me an Error

Comment: Come on a bit own research would be great. [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29140402)

Answer (score 0):

If your List contains OPBList objects, you cannot put them into an Array that contains String objects.

In your case you should do

```
OPBList[] arr = list123.toArray(new OPBList[] {});
```

according to the documentation

> public class ArrayStoreException
>   extends RuntimeException
>   Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.

Comment: thanks for your interest, the point is I want to compare those "objects" with some strings .....

Comment: I see your Object has 3 properties:
id, company, country.

What is it that you want to compare? And then what do you want your method to return?

Comment: well there are 2 more properties, the point is theres one property thats called "CEO" and I write a void method and give that method some paremeter, which company,which country and so an, and then I want to write a logic which compares those paremeters of that method with my properties, because I want then a return which give me back who is the CEO of that company (this is just an example)