# How to convert a list of objects to a multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list of objects (result from a select query), I want to convert it into an array and I want to put each column of the query in a column in the array. I have tried many solutions in the forum but I haven't found a solution.

In my bean I have the following list:

```
private List<PhBonCmd> listEntree; // The PhBonCmd is an object model imported  has attributes like codeprod , quant ,...
.....
String sql ="select c.codeprod as codeprod , c.quant as quant ,c.date_cmd as date_cmd, c.date_expir as date_expir,c.numbco as numbco, c.auteur as auteur,"
            +"c.idcmd as idcmd ,f.nomfourn as nomfourn ,coalesce(c.quant_livre, 0) as quant_livre ,m.libelle as libelle "
            +"from commandes c,listeproduit m,fournisseur f "
            +"where c.codeprod=m.codeproduit and c.fourn=f.idfourn and c.statut='IN' and c.numbco ='"+getNumbco()+"' ";

   listEntree =  (List<PhBonCmd>) this.bcService.execRequete(sql);//Here the results of the sql query
```

Now what I want is to put each column of the List (`listEntree`) in a multidimensional arraylist, so as if I want to access to a specific single value in of the arraylist, I do so.

Comment: first get type of result of executed request, after that if it's multi-dimensional then `List<PhBonCmd>` casting is right, otherwise intialize `listEntree = new List<PhBonCmd>` and add each item

Comment: Hello I've Found the solution given by Dans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773264/convert-listobject-to-string-in-java

Comment: Solution Founded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773264/convert-listobject-to-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting to `List<PhBonCmd>`? . The ResultSet is by default multidimensional. If you want to convert to a multidimensional List, you can do it by processing the ResultSet.

If you are using Spring , you can use [RowMapper](http://www.javatpoint.com/RowMapper-example) or [ResultSetExtractor](http://www.javatpoint.com/ResultSetExtractor-example) to get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I want to put the results of the query in an array and from there , i want to access to elements of the array . Have  things like this array1[row][col]

Comment: Can you please create this as a comment instead a answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason of doing that, when you have OOP power, but here it is. 
You have to use [reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html) to get know fields (lets say columns if you wish) of `PhBonCmd` on fly:

```
Class clazz = PhBonCmd.class;
Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();

String[][] myDemensionalArray = new String[fields.length()][listEntree.size()]; 
for(int i=0; i < fields.length(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j < listEntree.size(); j++){
              myDemensionalArray[i][j] = fields[i].get(listEntree.get(j));
        }
}
```