# Convert List<String> to new Object[]{}

Tags: java

I have this:

```
data.put(1, 
            new Object[] { listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(),
            listUserColumns.get(field++).getName(), listUserColumns.get(field++).getName() });
```

And i want to cast this `listUserColums` (List of type String) directly to new `Object[]`( of type `java.lang.object`) but don`t know how?

Comment: What does each call to `getName()` return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert List<Object> to String\[\] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773264/convert-listobject-to-string-in-java)

Comment: `Object[] objects = listUserColumns.stream().map(o -> o.getName()).toArray()`

Comment: What you have there is not really a `List<String>` though, is it? It looks like a list of some sort of class that has a `getName()` method.

Comment: Your code does not seem consistent with your description.  If `listUserColumns` has type `List<String>` then the elements you retrieve from it do not have a method named "getName".  If it *were* really a `List<String>`, though, then `List.toArray()` would do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are intended to obtain and it is not clear from the question.

When you need to get array of names for all elements in your list, you can use `Stream<T>`

```
Object[] names = listUserColumns.stream().map(c -> c.getName()).toArray();
```

However, there is no way to *cast this listUserColums*, since array is the inner representation of `ArrayList`. You can create a new array that contains references to the same elements as the list with this

```
Object[] elements = listUserColumns.toArray();
```

In your case it looks like `listUserColumns` is not `List<String>`, that's why the results of these methods would be different (In the first case array of string, and in the second case array of your custom types).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you want is more like

```
data.put(1, listUserColumns.stream().map(c -> c.getName()).toArray());
```

for a sub set

```
data.put(1, listUserColumns.subList(from, to)
                           .stream().map(c -> c.getName()).toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()) method:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.toArray()
```

Which:

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element).