# String[] to Object[] Java

Tags: java, jtable, jcombobox, japplet

Is there a workaround for casting a `String[]` to `Object[]`? I keep getting an error when using this.
I am trying to insert into a `jTable` and it gives me error saying I am trying to convert type `String` to type `Object`...

Here I am getting dates and inserting it into object months.

```
    // Create calendar and format to first sunday of the year.
    Calendar c;
    Object[] months = new String[52];
    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH,0);
    c.set(Calendar.DATE, 5);
    // Format Date and insert into months object array
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyy");
    for (int i =0; i < 52; i++){
        months[i] = df.format(c.getTime());
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
    }

    //Insert Months array into jComboBox
    jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(months));
    ...
    ...

    //Action performed retrieves selection from jComboBox and insert into table

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        // object[] o gets selection from selectedItem()
        Object[] o = (Object[]) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();

        //error checking to println
        System.out.println(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() + "    ");

        // create DefaultTableModel and insert into row zero with the object selected
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) weeklyCalendar.getModel();

        //insert into row, throws error
        model.insertRow(0, o);
    }
```

soo I guess I am getting a string from `getSelectedItem()` and trying to cast it to an `Object[]` with throws the error exception...what can I do to get around that?

Comment: The answer is posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java Just do the invert

Comment: `getSelectedItem` returns an `Object`, not a `String[]`.

Comment: Yes, for that line, it would not be returning an array at all. What are you trying to do exactly with the array?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't return an object. Tells my string

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jComboBox1.getSelectedObjects()` instead if you want an array.

Though not necessary for String, you may want to call `.toString()` on the returned Object when this line executes, just in case you happen to be storing Objects that are not String.

```
//error checking to println
System.out.println(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() + "    ");
```

Note that the `.getSelectedObjects()` method wouldn't be the preferred one to use, as it's still only returning a single element in an Object[] array. If you need an array, it would be easier just to use `.getSelectedItem()` and store the result in an array after the fact.

*Edited to reflect comment feedback.

Comment: Ahh thank you! You very wise man! I guess if I would have done some research, I would have found out that I can get and Object.

Comment: This is kind of erroneous, sorry. `getSelectedObjects` only returns a single element array and according to the doc is implemented for compatibility reasons with ItemSelectable. Also you don't need to call toString if an object is in a String concatenation expression: it is called automatically.

Comment: I agree, but thought I attempted to answer the question based on what he was trying to do. The toString() call I usually put in just to be consistent, such that if you have an object other than String being stored, you can still do a valid print. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast the complete String array to Object Array. You will have to cast elements individually. Create a method to cast all elements of type String to Object.

Comment: Even if this were the problem this is not necessarily true because arrays are covariant in Java. So for example `Object[] objs = new String[] { "hello" }; String[] strs = (String[])objs;` is a valid cast. On the other hand, `Object[] objs = { "hello" }; String[] strs = (String[])objs;` *will* throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The two important lines are here:

```
jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(months));

Object[] o = (Object[]) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
```

You aren't trying to cast a `String[]` to an `Object[]` but rather a `String` to an `Object[]` since `getSelectedItem` returns a single item.

I believe what you are wanting is just this:

```
Object o = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
```

Or this which will be a valid cast:

```
String s = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
```