# Mapping all `@QueryParam` to `JSON` data structure

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, classcastexception, query-string

I'm trying to map all `@QueryParam` of my `JAX-RS Jersey` application to a `JSON` data structure as follows:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/submit")
public String submit(@Context UriInfo info) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = info.getQueryParameters();

    JSONObject toInsert = new JSONObject();
    toInsert.accumulate("id", params.get("id").get(0));
    toInsert.accumulate("user", params.get("user").get(0));

    //params.remove("id");      have also like to delete these two
    //params.remove("user");    to avoid having duplicates in
    //                          the next rows

    JSONArray questions = new JSONArray();
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : params.entrySet()){
        String[] values = (String[]) entry.getValue().toArray();
        String key = entry.getKey();
        questions.put(key, values);

    } 

    toInsert.accumulate("questions", questions);

    return toInsert;
}
```

Unfortunately I get an Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
rest.Forms.submit(Forms.java:195)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:350)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:320)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I also tried the following after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java), it doesn't throw an exception but the result is semantically wrong.
If I substitute the inner for loop as follows:

```
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : params.entrySet()){
        List<String> values = entry.getValue();
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object[] objectArray = values.toArray();
        questions.put(key, Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class));
    }
```

The result in this case is composed in the "questions" part only as the list of keys, and I also want the associated values.
Thank you in advance

```
{ "id" : "f5475dc0-c8ce-11e3-9c1a-0800200c9a66",
  "questions" : [ "id",
      "l_name",
      "f_name",
      "citizenship",
      "like",
      "user"
    ],
  "user" : "gigi"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually cast the output of `toArray()` in that fashion.  You need to supply the type to the `toArray()` call so that it returns an array of the appropriate type.

For instance:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("foo");
    list.add("bar");
    String[] arr1 = (String[]) list.toArray(); // this throws a ClassCastException
    String[] arr2 = list.toArray(new String[0]); // this works
```

You just need to replace this line

```
        String[] values = (String[]) entry.getValue().toArray();
```

with this one

```
        String[] values = entry.getValue().toArray(new String[0]);
```

and your code should work.