# Difference between toArray(T[] a) and toArray()

Tags: java, list, toarray

I've been learning how to program with java and I haven't got any clear explanation about the difference of `LinkedList`'s `toArray(T[] a)` and `toArray()` method. The second one simply returns all of the elements within the LinkedList object as an array, right? But, what about the first one?

EDIT :

I mean, I read the documentation from oracle, it says :

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper
>   sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the
>   returned array is that of the specified array. **If the list fits in
>   the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is
>   allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of
>   this list. If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare
>   (i.e., the array has more elements than the list), the element in the
>   array immediately following the end of the list is set to null. (This
>   is useful in determining the length of the list only if the caller
>   knows that the list does not contain any null elements.)**
>
> Like the toArray() method, this method acts as bridge between
>   array-based and collection-based APIs. Further, this method allows
>   precise control over the runtime type of the output array, and may,
>   under certain circumstances, be used to save allocation costs.

I don't understand the meaning of the sentences displayed in bold.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Suppose you've a `List<String>`, and you want to convert it to `String[]`. Let's see the working of two methods:

```
List<String> source = new LinkedList<String>();
// Fill in some data

Object[] array1 = source.toArray();
String[] array2 = source.toArray(new String[source.size()]);
```

See the difference? The first one simply creates an `Object[]`, because it doesn't know the type of the type parameter `<T>`, while the second one just fills up the `String[]` you passed (which is what you want). You would almost always need to use the 2nd method.

Comment: What about using `String[] array3 = (String[]) source.toArray();`? I take it this is not recommended, but why not?

Comment: @jamsandwich I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13647072/4236274) in a different question. It might provide some explanation.

Comment: Use toArray(new String[0]). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093

Answer (score 4):

There are two differences :

1. The first returns `T[]` while the second returns `Object[]`
2. The first accepts an array as an argument, and if this array is large enough, it uses this array to store the elements of the Collection, instead of creating a new one.