# Class Cast Exception when passing array of Serializables from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, arrays, serialization

I have an array containing serializable objects and am trying to use Intent's putExtra() and Bundle's getSerializable().  However, I am getting a class cast exception and don't understand why.

Below is the code.  UserInfo is my own class which implements Serializable, and I have been able to pass individual UserInfo objects between activities.  I've only ran into this problem when attempting to use an array.

**Code sending the serializable:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent( JOIN_GROUP ); //JOIN_GROUP is a constant string

String user_ids[] = packet.userIDs();

int length = user_ids.length;
UserInfo users[] = new UserInfo[length];

for ( int i = 0; i < length; ++i )
    users[i] = getUserByID( user_ids[i] );

intent.putExtra( USERS_IN_GROUP, users );
```

**Code retrieving the serializable:**

```
Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();          
String action = intent.getAction();

if ( action.equals(IMService.JOIN_GROUP) )
{   
    //CLASS CAST EXCEPTION
    UserInfo users[] = (UserInfo[]) extra.getSerializable( IMService.USERS_IN_GROUP ); 
}
```

Here is the error:

[image]

**Question**

I'm aware I could probably just use a different data structure, but I would like to understand why the array does not work since arrays are serializable?

**EDIT:** SnyersK was able to get a simpler but similar scenario to work. 
So I tried the same thing, and I still get the same exception.  It turned my array of Tests into an Object when retrieving the array, which results in the casting exception.

**My Test object:**

```
package types;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String hello = "hello";

}
```

**Code to pass the array of Test objects:**

```
Test myArray[] = new Test[] { new Test(), new Test() };
Intent i = new Intent( this, Login.class );
i.putExtra( "key", myArray );
```

**Code to retrieve the array of Test objects:**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Test array[] = (Test[]) extras.getSerializable( "key" ); //Class Cast Exception
```

Comment: Update the question with some error log.

Comment: Seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14333555/233048

Comment: I just tried to pass an array of a serializable object myself, and i'm not seeing any errors.
You're 100% positive you're not putting another extra using the same string before you're launching your second activity?

Comment: @SnyersK That is strange.  I am 100% positive.  There is only one place in one class where I make this happen.  And changing the data structure to an ArrayList worked.  I added many log statements to the code as well to make sure these two snippets were being executed.  You're saying you didn't get a class cast exception on an array of your own custom serializable objects?  For whatever reason, the runtime object turns into an instance of the Object class instead of remaining as a UserInfo array.

Comment: Yes, i wrote a quick test using a custom object `Test` which only contained a string and implemented Serializable. I made an array containing 5 objects and put this as an extra when starting a second activity. It all worked just fine. I had no errors and my objects were all there in my second activity.

Comment: @SnyersK
That is super weird.  I don't know why it didn't work for me then.  Maybe my eclipse or installed plugins are buggy? Idk. Just changing the array to an ArrayList spit out an ArrayList on the other end.  Using the array spit out an Object on the other end.

Comment: That's really weird indeed. I'm using Android Studio, but your IDE shouldn't be able to affect this. I was using a very simple object though, maybe that's why it worked for me. I did notice that your custom object does have to implement serializable, but since you said that your `UserInfo` does, I really don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: @SnyersK I tried out what you said, and I got the same exception.  I used 2 different activities than the original 2 involved in the problem.  I edited my question with the Test object I used, and the code to pass/retrieve the object (which was place in the activities' onCreate methods.

Comment: I literally just copied your code and it's running fine here. On what version of android are you testing? I'm using a nexus 5 running 5.0.1

Comment: @SnyersK
I tried it on 2 phones.  `Model number: HTC Sensation 4G,  Android version: 2.3.4` and `Model number: Galaxy Nexus, Android version 4.2.2`.

Comment: My guess is that It has something to do with the version. I just tested on a Galaxy Nexus virtual device running 4.2.2 and i get the classCastException like you say. Same thing on my Galaxy S3 running android 4.3.

Comment: @SnyersK
ah hah! We have found the source of the problem ! Considering both the putExtra() and getSerializable() methods are supposed to support API level 1 (according to the docs), this is definitely a bug.  Post an answer, and I'll accept it.   Goob job, Snyers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug on older versions of Android. (Version 5.0.1 is the only version tested on which it works like expected, perhaps it works from 5.0 and up)

**The bug**

Let's say we have an Array of an object called `User` which implements `Serializable`.

```
User[] users;
```

When we try to pass this array to another activity through an intent like this

```
intent.putExtra("myKey", users);
```

our `users` will get converted to `Object[]`.

If we try to get our array from the intent in the second activity like so

```
User[] users = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myKey");
```

We will get a ClassCastException.

From the docs, we can conclude that this shouldn't be a problem since `Array` is a serializable class, and `putExtra(String key, Serializable value)` has been added since `api 1`.

If you want to pass an `Array` through an intent on Android versions prior to Android 5.0.1 (maybe some older versions work aswell, but up to Android 4.3 it is NOT working)
You'll have to work around it. You could do this by converting your `Array` to an `ArrayList`.

**EDIT**

another workaround is copying your extra to a new array, thus, not having to cast it. I'm not sure about the positive/negative consequences of the method though. It would look like this:

```
Object[] array = (Object[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
User[] parsedArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length, User[].class);
```

I found this method here: [How to convert object array to string array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java).

Comment: You should mention that User implements Serializable.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be nit-picky, It gets converted to `Object`, not `Object[]`. And if anyone's worried about a waste of space with using an `ArrayList`, they can always pass in the initial  capacity they want to the constructor, achieving nearly the same amount of space as using a basic array. (I say "nearly" because ArrayLists have a few more instance variables, but no big deal.)  Good answer.

Comment: My stacktrace says it's an `Object[]`.
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to my.package.testing.Test[]`

Comment: Oh okay I think I just didn't expland the stack traces prodcued in the logcat all the way (and tbh idk  how). Thanks again.

Comment: i've seen other people write it as `[Ljava.lang.Object;` aswell. I suppose the ' [L ' means it's an array. I added another possible workaround btw.

Comment: this is the best solution ever for this bug

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
intent.putExtra( USERS_IN_GROUP, users );
```

with

```
intent.putExtra( USERS_IN_GROUP, new ArrayList<UserInfo>(Arrays.asList(users)));
```

Comment: I get a compiler error using this: `The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<UserInfo>)`.  I thought that would work too considering the description for asList() says it returns a serializable List.

Comment: try bundle.putparcelable()

Comment: @Zygotelnit I believe you, but the problem is the compiler error when putting the extra.  At the moment it doesn't matter what I cast the returned object from `getSerializable()` to since that won't happen until run time.

Comment: UserInfo needs to implement `Serializable` I guess

Comment: It does.  I've been able to use getSerializable() on it for the past few weeks.

Comment: I gave this an upvote for now since it's a simple solution to the problem but doesn't answer my question about why the array does not work.  
I'm just going to change the data structure to an ArrayList instead of converting it to a list and passing it to the ArrayList constructor, but it's the same idea.

Comment: It's a solution to the exception but does not answer the question (at the bottom of my post).  I'll accept the first answer that does.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( JOIN_GROUP ); //JOIN_GROUP is a constant string

String user_ids[] = packet.userIDs();

int length = user_ids.length;
UserInfo users[] = new UserInfo[length];

for ( int i = 0; i < length; ++i )
    users[i] = getUserByID( user_ids[i] );

Bundle bnd=new Bundle();
bnd.putSerializable(USERS_IN_GROUP, users);
```

while sending you are attaching to intent and while retrvng you are reading from the bundle (which is intent extras).

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I've been able to pass serializable objects successfully using my approach for the past few weeks.  I only ran into the problem when using an array.  So I'm not sure why this would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `UserInfo` inner class or a separate java class file?

If it is an inner class, then the parent class also should be Serializable.

If not, make `UserInfo` class implement `Parcelable` and use

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(USERS_IN_GROUP, new ArrayList<UserInfo>(Arrays.asList(users)));
```

Comment: It's a separate class.

Comment: Implementing Parcelable takes much more effort than implementing Serializable, and efficiency is not an issue at the moment so Serializable is what I'd like to use.  Also, I would have to change many lines of code since the methods to pass UserInfo as Serializable objects are different than Parcelable.  I'm making a chatting app so UserInfo objects are passed around quite a bit.