# Is Array Serializable/Parcelable if object is Serializable/Parcelable

Tags: java, android, arrays, serialization

I am looking to pass an array of object from activity to activity in Android. I understand that the optimal way to do this is having your passed objects implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android).

However, if I am passing an *array* of these objects, will this still work, considering you are now passing an array of objects that implement those interfaces, rather than the object itself? If not, would I instead need to extend a class such as `ArrayList` and implement these interfaces, and pass that 'array' object instead?

Comment: what happens when you try to serialise array?

Comment: After looking around some more, I found [this](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=34789), which leads me to believe that the array does not add any complication to the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, calling serialize on an array causes the array to recursively call serialize on its members. However, it appears there may be a bug affecting this in Android versions prior to 5.0.1 https://stackoverflow.com/a/28720450/1541763

It seems that parceling an array follows this logically, but that unmarhsalling is a little more complicated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781119/1541763

Comment: Would this same concept apply to the Parcelable interface as well?

Comment: It seems that parceling an array follows this logically, but that unmarhsalling is a little more complicated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10781119/1541763