# inconsistent behavior when typecasting Serializable to File[] from intent getSerializableExtra()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization

I'm sending File[] array between two applications in an intent.
On the receiving app I have a code that typecasts Serializable to File[].

```
File[] files = (File[]) intent.getSerializableExtra(RESULT_FILES);
```

I've been testing it and it works fine.

However when other guy was using same code with same application, he got type cast exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.io.File[]

So I'm curios to know why Intent.getSerializableExtra() returns File[] object in my environment and Object[] with someone else?

Has that changed between android api or java versions?

As requested in comment, extra is put to intent with this code:

```
File[] files = fileCollection.compressAllQuitely();
intent.putExtra(RESULT_FILES, files);
```

So in a nutshell.
I made application a.
I tested with application b. getSerializableExtra returns File[]
Another guys made own app c and tested agains application a. getSerializableExtra returns Object[]

Comment: Show code where you are putting extras

Comment: Added code for putting extras

Comment: I think this answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28720450/3978990

Comment: Thanks man!

I spent good while trying to find that explanation.