# implicit cast char array to int array

Tags: java, arrays

I currently have a char array

```
char [] firstArray = {'1', 'a', 'c', '4', 'q'};
```

I want to implicitly self-cast this array to a int one. I mean not to create a new int array and to try to assign him the index's values of this one, but to change this array to an int array.

Comment: You can not. That's not a valid conversion. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let's say you can do it. What will `a` turn into? `97`? `0`? `-1`?

Comment: You can convert an array of A into an array of B if B is a subclass of A ([like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java)), but `int` is not a subclass of `char`.

Comment: I'm trying to use the cesaer chiper code. As far as I've been told a char array should be read from the console and after that a shift (for example +5) should been typed. This should transform my array (first in an int array) and after that using the shift variable the same array with new values should be displayed.

Comment: What is a "cesaer chiper"?

Comment: transforming is not casting. transforming usually means you create new object from (or based on) an existing one

Comment: If you are doing a caesar cipher, you'd want to use just `char[]` or `String`. I can't see why you want to use an `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the declared type of an object with casting. Casting will allow you to treat an object as another type, not to change it's type.

let's say I have this code:

```
String s = '';
Object o;
```

I can do this:

```
o = (Object)s;
```

what it will do - o will have a reference to s and will treat it as an Object. however, s is still a String, nothing we can do to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a `char` array to an `int` array. The only way you can achieve this is to create a new `int` array, iterate through the old `firstArray` and store the `int` value of the `chars` into the new array.