# What's the difference between the generic array and the generic value?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting

```
public class Array<T> {
    private Object[] array;
    public Array(int sz) {
        array = new Object[sz];
    }
    // ....
    public T get(int index) { return (T)array[index]; }
    public T[] rep() { return (T[])array; } 
}
```

Why does the compiler say that `(T[])array` is unchecked cast, and then `ClassCastException` is thrown when I use the `rep()` method?
And why is this exception not thrown when I use the `get()` method()?

Comment: Your problem have nothing to with the generics. This can be interesting for you: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13647072/5333936)

Comment: Short answer:  You cannot cast to a generic type, due to erasure.  Use `List<T>` in place of `Object[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is this exception not thrown when I use the get() method()?

There are two reasons for this :

1. Assuming that no elements were added to `array` in your program, the `array` is going to be initialized with `sz` number of `null` values.. The statement `(T)array[index]` is trying to cast a `null` into a `T` (where `T` essentially gets replace by `Object` through type erasure). A `null` can be cast into any type so this is not an issue.
2. Assuming that some elements are added to `array` in your program, the only way that the statement `(T)array[index]` will work without any issues is if the element at position `index` is of the same type or a subtype used for instantiating `Array` (e.g `Array<Number> arr = new Array<Number>` and `arr[index]` is 1. This won't be an issue; however, try inserting a `String` at `arr[index]` and you are bound to get a `ClassCastException` from the `get` method as well)

> Why does the compiler say that (T[])array is unchecked cast, and then ClassCastException is thrown when I use the rep()

The only way for you to get a `ClassCastException` is that the type represented by `T` is not the same as the type of elements that `array` can hold. For example, doing something as follows will result in a `ClassCastException` :

```
Array<Integer> a = new Array<Integer>();
Integer[] intArray = a.rep();//ClassCastException
```

Here, `T[]` represents an `Integer[]` so there are no issues in compiling the code; however, at runtime, `array` is of type `Object[]`. An array of `Object` cannot be downcast to an array of `Integer`. It would also help to know that arrays are dynamically created by the JVM unlike other classes.

One way to fix this would be to instantiate `Array` as `Array<Object> arr = new Array<Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

In `get()`, you just care about the actual runtime type of the elements inside the array, which I assume are right because you have some method that puts only `T`s into the array. The array's actual runtime type doesn't matter.

In `rep()`, you care about the array object's actual runtime type, because you are casting it to `T[]`. You created the array with actual runtime type `Object[]`, so the cast to `T[]` will always be incorrect unless `T` happens to be `Object`.